# Is 30 minutes jogging enough for good amount of Sugar consumption?

Tags: exercise, jogging, sugar

I do jogging in the morning, around 5 days a week, from 6 to 6.30.
I jog for around 1.3 Kms and then return walking from there.

Also, I consume some sugar content throughout the day, like tea (at 8AM), curd(in breakfast, 9AM), coffee with biscuits(at 11 AM and then at 4 PM), all these with around 1 to 1.5 teaspoon Sugar added in each.

All I want to know if I am doing enough to compensate my sugar consumption?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have more than 1 question, split them up. Use this one for your sugar question and ask about road impact on a separate question.

Comment: Can you explain your question, what does that mean 'will jogging harm you' . Why should it harm you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calories used during jogging varies greatly based on the incline and your body statistics. The "average male" jogging for 30 minutes burns about 250 calories.

There are around 15 calories in a teaspoon of sugar. You have about 6 teaspoons maximum per day, totaling 90 calories.

> 1. Am I doing enough in jogging so as to compensate my sugar consumption?

**Probably**

---

Note: Converting sugar into energy does not work like you think it does based on this question. Just convert your calories for the day of all food and make sure its equal (or less if trying to lose weight) than your Total Daily Energy Expenditure (TDEE).

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty important to note that while it may be enough now, your body won't always burn the same amount of calories. The human body is amazing at adapting to new situations, hence why weight training is so effective. Similarly, with jogging, as you keep repeating this process, your body will burn less and less calories over time as your energy pathways become more efficient. Think about it, that's how people get better at running (or anything really), you just keep doing it, and you will progress. So assuming you burn the "average" calories mentioned by @JJosaur, 250, this number will slowly decrease over time and you will have to change up your training, i.e run for longer or run the same distance faster.

Additionally, this is actually pretty important but no one EVER mentions it. The more sugar you consume on a regular basis, the more insulin and leptin resistant you will become over time. The same principle of adaptation occurs here. I'm not going to give many of the details here since I already wrote them in another answer here: [Impact of weekly collossal cheat days](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31206/impact-of-weekly-collossal-cheat-days/31216#31216)

But basically, this example should suffice:

Here's how it looks:

You eat some wild salmon and a big sweet potato. The beta cells in your pancreas produce insulin in response to your blood glucose level.
Insulin stimulates leptin production in your fat cells.
Leptin levels go up, triggering the hypothalamus to decrease appetite.
High levels of leptin also tell your pancreas to stop making insulin.

But here's how it looks when you have leptin resistance (that you gained over time by eating sugar regularly) :

You eat some wild salmon and a big sweet potato with some pop tarts (or anything sugary). The beta cells in your pancreas produce insulin in response to your blood glucose level.
Insulin stimulates leptin production in your fat cells, overwhelming your body.
Leptin levels go up but leptin resistance starts to set in.
High levels of leptin try to tell your pancreas to stop making insulin, but you're leptin resistant so the pancreas doesn't get the message to stop!
We now have chronically high levels of insulin, leading to insulin resistance.

You are now way more likely to store food as fat and will find it harder to feel "full". When people eat delicious food and can't stop until they hate themselves, it is because of this, your brain THOUGHT you were hungry because of the leptin and insulin resistance you built up over time.

For the purposes of this question though, as long as you progress in your workouts, you'll be fine.